# Unable to select value in the dropdown in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

Select does select the value in the dropdown but doesn't place the value in the field.
[below is the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pl91h.png)

I am using:

```
Select companyList = new Select(createRequestPageObjects.company);
companyList.selectByVisibleText("PLACO");
```

Webelement is defined in my object file :

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//label[contains(text(),'Société')]/following-sibling::div/select")
public WebElement company;
```

After the selection, When I try to print

```
System.out.println(companyList.getFirstSelectedOption().getText());
```

then it does print "PLACO" , but on screen it's not selected because of which the further dependent fields do not get the list values as required.

As suggested in the other existing queries, I tried using `sendkeys` and also tried fetching the possible options in the list by `companyList.getOptions()` and then clicking when the required option while iterating. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried selectByIndex?

Comment: It worked after adding wait before the selection. Thanks for the help.